# Is motorcycle ABS necessary for newbie riders riding in India?

Tags: motorcycle, abs, india

ABS is now being installed and offered as an option on a few motorcycles in India. Most of them however, are only on the front-wheel. Rear wheels don't still have ABS, but apparently come with a wheel spin sensor.

Considering the use-case of a 200cc, 20.5 bhp, 18.5 Nm (13.6 pound-feet) of torque, 150 kg motorcycle, on mostly city roads, and sometimes on highway roads - does one REALLY need ABS on a bike?

Can one compensate for lack of ABS, by training one-self regularly?

Please consider me a newbie in terms of motorcycling when considering an answer.

Your response is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a lifelong motorcyclist, and I vote to close as being primarily opinion-based. I certainly have one, but SE endeavors to be a fact-based community.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, David. I hoped that my question didn't come across as something that needs a nebulous answer, but i'm afraid that it seems so at the moment. If one additional person concurs with you, i'll delete the question. Thank you.

Comment: This is off topic as it's not really about maintenance, but driving @JayanthKumar. My personal view as a motorcyclist is that anything that keeps the front wheel from locking up is worthwhile no matter where you live, however I haven't seen any statistics to back that up.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment, @Jayanth Kumar. For me, the question's use of the words "REALLY need" moves us into opinion-land. One can discuss the differences, benefits, and negatives about ABS while still remaining in fact-land.

Comment: In my opinion, **you do not need ABS in your situation**. If you want to improve your braking skills without ABS, go to a large, empty parking lot or parking garage. Accelerate, and then try to stop as fast as possible. Try it using only the front, only the rear, and both brakes. If you become familiar with when your wheels lock up on different types of surfaces (pavement, concrete, wet/dry, etc), you can "train" yourself to not need ABS. Happy riding, and "keep the rubber side down"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have reputation so I cant comment. anyways, abs is a safety thing. it stops your wheel from locking when too much braking pressure is applied.

Now, citing a scenario in the city when you are cruising at the main road nearing an intersection at a speed of 50kms when suddenly a car entered the intersection at high speed. you might be surprised of that car and suddenly squeezed the front brakes so hard that it pull locked your tyres and throw you off into the air. ABS prevents that kind of things happening